# QT SQLITE Database wont open

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

I am having an extremely annoying problem and it doesn't make sense to me whats wrong.  I am creating a multiple form ATM app but for some reason my DB is saying its open in the app but in the output it is throwing the error: **QSqlQuery::exec: database not open**

Here is the mainmenu.cpp file where I create the first instance of the DB

```
mainMenu::mainMenu(QWidget *parent) :QMainWindow(parent),ui(newUi::mainMenu)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    atmDB = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE","myConnection");
    atmDB.setDatabaseName(Path_to_DB);
    QFileInfo checkFile(Path_to_DB);
}
```

Here in the login.cpp file it displays on the screen "Database connected"

```
login::login(QWidget *parent) :QDialog(parent),ui(new Ui::login)
{
ui->setupUi(this);

QSqlDatabase logindb;

logindb = QSqlDatabase::database("myConnection",true);
bool x = logindb.open();


if(!x){
    ui->loginStatusL->setText("No connection to log-in database!");
}
else
    ui->loginStatusL->setText("Database connected!");
}
```

But when the user pushes the button to login it it throws the SqlQuery error,

```
void login::on_loginLoginB_clicked()
{
QSqlDatabase loginB;
loginB = QSqlDatabase::database("myConnection",true); //open database

QString email, password;
email = ui->loginEmailbox->text();
password = ui->loginPassbox->text();
pubEmail = email;

if(!loginB.isOpen()){
    ui->loginStatusL->setText("Connection to database lost");
    return;
}

QSqlQuery qry;

if(qry.exec("SELECT * FROM userRecords WHERE email = '"+email+"' and password='"+password+"'")){
    int count = 0;
    while(qry.next()){
        count++;
    }
    if(count==1){
        userMenu usermenu;
        atmDB.close();
        usermenu.setModal(true);
        usermenu.exec();
    }
    else
        ui->loginStatusL->setText("Login failed.  Email or password incorrect.");
}

}
```

I also have the same problem in my register.cpp file and it follows the same logic.

Comment: Most of this code is unrelated; narrow it down to an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to just know why wouldn't the `QSqlQuery::exec()` work, that's because you haven't told it anything about the database that it should run the query on.
The initialization should look more like:

```
QSqlDatabase loginB;
//code omitted...
QSqlQuery qry(loginDB); //Tell QSqlQuery which database to work with
//call qry.exe() here
```

I'd bet that it's the same problem in your register.cpp.

Comment: SQLite does not use passwords (nor any other form of authentication)

Comment: @el.pescado you're absolutely correct, thank you. This is something that I oversaw. I've edited the answer to reflect that.